# Apex on cloned copy of live redirects to the live application server

Tags: oracle-apex

We have a bit of a strange issue.
We have created a copy of our production database on some new hardware to do some testing.
We also run some APEX 19.2 applications on that database so we setup a new ORDS 19.2 installation on a test server running Tomcat 8.5 .

Every time we try and test on the new test server, we are instantly redirected to the production URL.
We get a http 302 response with the production URL in the header, originating from the test server, it's not coming from a proxy or load balancer (Unless it is somehow impersonating). This happens before any resources are loaded.
It's not in any specific application either. We DO have a redirect written on most of the apps to force users into a centralised login app, but we aren't hitting that. We also don't get redirected to the same place in this instance, it just takes us to the generic workspace login.

There are no url rewrites defined at the Tomcat layer.

We have other Apex installs on this server that work just fine, though they are older versions of Apex.

It seems like Apex 19.2 'Knows' where it is supposed to be running based one something in the database that we haven't updated. And redirects you if you use the wrong URL/Server. But I can't find any reference to it having that behaviour, or where the setting would be. The only relevant setting I can find in the instance settings is supposed to just be used for generating emails.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before or have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It does appear to be the email settings, one of my team worked it out.
Seems to be only if there is unsent mail in the queue, as soon as you launch apex it tries to authenticate with the configured server.
He updated APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_PLATFORM_PREFS with the new URL and it works fine again.
To test we set it to a different server after the queue had been emptied and the issue did not return.